# How to remove newline from output?

Tags: shell

Hashing passwords in shell (sha512) breaks the line.
How to get a result in one line?

The script for hashing:

```
password="abc123"
hashPassw="$(/bin/echo -n "${password}" | openssl dgst -binary -sha512 | openssl enc -base64)"
echo "${hashPassw}"
```

Output is (why breaks the line?):

```
xwtd2ev7b1HQnUEytxcMnSB1CnhS8AaA9lZY8DEOgQBW5nY8NMmgCw6UAHb1RJXB
afwjAszrMSA5JxxDRpUH3A==
```

Should be one line:

```
xwtd2ev7b1HQnUEytxcMnSB1CnhS8AaA9lZY8DEOgQBW5nY8NMmgCw6UAHb1RJXBafwjAszrMSA5JxxDRpUH3A==
```

Answer (score 28):

From the [OpenSSL Wiki](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Enc) for `enc`.

> To suppress this you can use in addition to -base64 the -A flag. This will produce a file with no line breaks at all.

So adding the additional `-A` flag will do the trick.

```
password="abc123"
hashPassw="$(/bin/echo -n "${password}" | openssl dgst -binary -sha512 | openssl enc -A -base64)"
echo "${hashPassw}"
```

Which outputs

```
xwtd2ev7b1HQnUEytxcMnSB1CnhS8AaA9lZY8DEOgQBW5nY8NMmgCw6UAHb1RJXBafwjAszrMSA5JxxDRpUH3A==
```

Answer (score 12):

Why do you think it should be one line? Base64 does wrap lines.

If you insist, your question boils down from "SHA512 SSL Base64 whatever" to "how do I remove newlines", for which there are many ways,

```
tr -d '\n'
```

being only one of them.

Comment: My script creates a hash of the password - for users Proftpd.
Password with a broken line does not authorize the users.
I did not know that base64 may be breaking.

Comment: @kpietru: Just FYI, the main purpose of Base64 was to encode binary data for email transfer, that's where the line break has its origins.

Comment: Actually 'pure' Base64 must not contain any line breaks, according to RFC 4648 - unless some specification requires it, like for MIME or PEM. Many base64 tools output line breaks for historical reasons, since MIME made Base64 popular as mentioned in the above comment. In the case of openssl it certainly makes sense that lines are wrapped at 64 characters, as required for PEM.

Comment: This command worked for me `openssl enc -A -base64`

Answer (score 0):

To remove the new line in openssl use the flag -A.

**Example**:

```bash
echo "password" | openssl base64 -A
```

Comment: According to `base64 --help` there is no -A flag. However you can pass 0 to -w flag if you want to disable line wrapping totally. Thanks

Comment: Oh! sorry man, I forgot to add openssl command.